# WASM/Yew - failed to resolve: could not find `unix` in `os`

Tags: windows, rust, webassembly, yew

### Building Yew App on Windows

I'm building a yew app alongside a rocket backend on Windows following
[this tutorial](https://erwabook.com/intro/create-a-browser-based-frontend-ui.html)
(although the tutorial is for a Linux environment). I'm trying to build the yew app
using `wasm-pack`. I'm not using the Linux subsystem to build the app, though
I do have it installed.

### Code / Configuration

[The repository](https://github.com/zachdelano/sentinel/tree/60ba68366fabd41fa3bfb84d5d2e4562bc5b07d2).

I have already installed the wasm toolchain and cargo make:

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

The following is my toolchain list:

```
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
1.30.0-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
Project root
├───backend           <-- rocket backend
|   ├───Cargo.toml
│   └───src
│       ├───bin
│       └───db
├───frontend          <-- yew frontend
│   ├───pkg
│   ├───src
|   ├───Cargo.toml
|   └───Makefile.toml
├───src
├───Cargo.toml
└───Makefile.toml
```

This is `rootdir\Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "sentinel"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["zachdelano <email>"]
edition = "2018"

[workspace]
members = ["backend", "frontend"]
```

This is `rootdir\Makefile.toml`:

```
[env]
CARGO_MAKE_EXTEND_WORKSPACE_MAKEFILE = "true"

[tasks.default]
clear = true
dependencies = ["build"]
```

This is `rootdir\frontend\Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
sentinel = { path = ".." }
yew = "0.17.3"
wasm-pack = "0.9.1"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.68"
web-sys = "0.3.45"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]
```

This is `rootdir\frontend\Makefile.toml`:

```
[tasks.default]
dependencies = ["create_wasm"]

[tasks.create_wasm]
command = "wasm-pack"
args = ["build", "--target", "web", "--out-name", "package", "--dev"] 
dependencies = ["build"]
```

### Expected result

I expect the app to finish building with no errors when I run
`cargo make`. The [Yew tutorial](https://yew.rs/docs/en/getting-started/build-a-sample-app/)
seems to indicate nothing else is needed.

### Actual output

I get a host of errors when running `cargo make` (from the root directory) like the following:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `unix` in `os`
  --> C:\Users\Zach\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\dirs-1.0.5\src\lin.rs:41:18
   |
41 |     use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStringExt;
   |                  ^^^^ could not find `unix` in `os`
```

See [the entire list of errors](https://github.com/zachdelano/sentinel/blob/60ba68366fabd41fa3bfb84d5d2e4562bc5b07d2/cargomake.txt#L139).

Is this a toolchain sort of thing? How can I fix this?

### Running `rustup update`

I get [the following output](https://github.com/zachdelano/sentinel/blob/529ada73d7fd2634e6c521f9ffe5637199f001a7/rustup_update.txt)
from running `rustup update`.

Now when I run `cargo make` from the root directory, I get different errors:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys`                                                                                                                                                                                     
  --> C:\Users\Zach\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\socket2-0.3.15\src\socket.rs:23:5
   |
23 | use crate::sys;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no `sys` in the root
```

See the [full list of errors](https://github.com/zachdelano/sentinel/blob/529ada73d7fd2634e6c521f9ffe5637199f001a7/cargomake2.txt).
Some of the code changed [in the repository](https://github.com/zachdelano/sentinel/tree/529ada73d7fd2634e6c521f9ffe5637199f001a7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  issue ended up being that I was trying to install `wasm-pack` and `web-sys`. I don't know why that was an issue but when I commented them out and ran `cargo make`, everything built just fine. I also deleted `target` and reran `cargo make` just to make sure.

```
[package]
name = "frontend"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["zachdelano <email>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
sentinel = { path = ".." }
yew = "0.17.3"
wasm-bindgen = "0.2.68"
# wasm-pack = "0.9.1"
# web-sys = "0.3.45"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]
```